# How to parameterise table name in ODBC query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, odbc

I have an ODBC connection to a database and I would like the user to be able to view data within any table. As this is an ASP.net application I cannot trust that the table name sent doesn't also contain nasties. I have tried using a parameterised query but I always get an error saying that I "*Must declare the table variable*" - this appears to be an issue because it is the table name

```
 string sql = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM ? ";
 OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(sql, dbConnection);
 command.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("@table", tableName));
 OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter();
 adapter.SelectCommand = command;
 adapter.Fill(tableData);
```

What is the best method to achieve this in a secure way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a stored procedure, it's the safest way.

Some hints:

1. You probably may also use the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace objects
2. Enclose your connection, command and adapter objects initializations in `using` statements

Here's a simple example:

```
string sqlStoredProcedure = "SelectFromTable";
using (OdbcConnection dbConnection = new OdbcConnection(dbConnectionString))
{
    dbConnection.Open();
    using (OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(sqlStoredProcedure, dbConnection))
    {
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("@table", tableName));
        using (OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(command))
        {
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            adapter.Fill(tableData);
        }
    }
}
```

Another way to go would be to retrieve all table names and validate the `tableName` string variable as an entry in the list, maybe using:

```
DataTable tables = dbConnection.GetSchema(OdbcMetaDataCollectionNames.Tables);
```

Here's a simple implementation based on your scenario:

```
string sql = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM {0}";
using (OdbcConnection dbConnection = new OdbcConnection(dbConnectionString))
{
    dbConnection.Open();

    DataTable tables = dbConnection.GetSchema(OdbcMetaDataCollectionNames.Tables);
    var matches = tables.Select(String.Format("TABLE_NAME = '{0}'", tableName));

    //check if table exists
    if (matches.Count() > 0)
    {
        using (OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(String.Format(sql, tableName), dbConnection))
        {
            using (OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(command))
            {
                adapter.SelectCommand = command;
                adapter.Fill(tableData);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //handle invalid value
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately I don't have access to the database to add things like SP's, so I need to do it all in the application. but this is an interesting solution. 

Also, would something like this http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/12/stored-procedures-and-orms-wont-save.html apply to your solution?

Comment: In the link you provided `EXEC(@query)` is called in the SQL stored procedure, after a dynamic query is build using the `@SearchTerm` parameter. So, the SQL developers should also take care of how they actually use the data and which are the risks of dynamic queries.

Comment: Just seen your edit, seems like the easiest way to do it, even if it is slightly less elegant. Thanks for your help!